# execute the runnable in a continuous loop

Tags: android, android-imageview

My code mainly decodes a series of bitmap objects to be displayed in an ImageView later. To get more control over the duration to display each image. So i implemented the code in a Runnable. Here is a snippet of that runnable.

```
 final File file[]=dir.listFiles();
 iv.postDelayed(
                 new Runnable() {

                     @Override
                     public void run() {

                         i++;



                        Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(file[i]);

                        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


                        iv.postDelayed(this, 5000);






    }
    }, 5000);
```

However, I don't seem to have a good control over the looping here. I am not able to use a for loop since "i" cant be assigned to zero in this case. This code works as long as the "file[i]" has a File reference to it. As soon as it displays all the images once, the app just force closes do to arrayindexoutofbounds exception. I just want to continue the loop infinitely. Any pointers?

Here decodeFile() calls another function to rescale the size of the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are doing, but why not use a [while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop instead? Something like `while (true) { }` would cause the infinite loop.

Comment: sorry, my bad. there is no "j" loop there. Question edited. Ok, will try the while loop out.

Answer (score 0):

sense you want to do some work that might take a while and you want do repeat it, try looking at an android component called service and send it the images by intent.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

probably an IntentService would be fine, and help alot

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an AsyncTask

File means a file array is given the task to be processed in the background.

Bitmap means you call publishProgress with your bitmap, you fetch it on the UI thread in onProgressUpdate

Void means you simply stop once it is done.

The good thing here is that the decoding is done on a background thread, but the iv.setBitmap is still called on the UI thread, which is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset to zero once you reach the end:

```
final File file[]=dir.listFiles();
iv.postDelayed(
             new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     if (i == file.length) {
                         i = 0;
                     }
                     else {
                         i++;
                     }

                    Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(file[i]);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    iv.postDelayed(this, 5000);
                }
            }, 5000);
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work. Tried with both for and while loops. App force closes again with arrayindexoutofbounds exception!

Comment: You don't need a while loop or a for loop. The call `iv.postdelayed(this, 5000);` is a recursive call which is its own logical loop.